# How can I use matplotlib to animate several graphs each with an advancing window of real-time data and utilizing blitting?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I currently have a working python program that simultaneously animates one or more graphs each with an advancing window of real-time data.  The program utilizes FuncAnimation and replots each graph using the axes plot routine. It is desired to show updates every second in the animation and the program is able to perform as expected when animating a few graphs. However, matplotlib cannot complete updates in a 1 second timeframe when attempting to animate several (>5) graphs.

Understanding that updating graphs in their entirety takes time, I am attempting to employ blitting to the animation process.

I have attempted to simplify and comment the code for an easier understanding.  The data I work with is a binary stream from a file. Frames of data within the stream are identified and marked prior to running the code below. Within each frame of data resides electronic signal values that are to be plotted. Each electronic signal has one or more data points within a single binary data frame. The ability to see up to a dozen plotted signals at the same time is desired. The code follows and is commented.

I employ a python deque to mimic a data window of 10 seconds. For each call to the FuncAnimation routine, 1 second of data is placed into the deque and then the deque in processed to produce a xValues and yValues array of data points.
At the bottom of the code is the FuncAnimation routine that is called every 1 second (DisplayAnimatedData). Within that routine are 2 print statements that I have used to determine that the data within the xValues and yValues arrays from the deque are correct and that the plot set_xlim for each graph is correctly being changed in a way to advance the window of animated data.

The plotting is kind of working. However, the xaxis tick values are not updated after the initial set of tick values are applied correctly using calls to set_xlim. And, I expected the yaxis ylim to automatically scale to the data. But it does not. How do I get the xaxis tick values to advance as the data window advances?  How to I get the yaxis tick values to display correctly?
Finally, you will notice that the code hides the xaxis of all graphs except the last one. I designed this thinking that although the set_xlim of each graph is called for each pass through the FuncAnimation, that no time is spent redrawing but one xaxis. I hope this will improve performance.
Your insight would be appreciated.

```
from matplotlib import animation
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from collections import deque
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

#PlotsUI is code created via Qt Designer
class PlotsUI(object):
    def setupUi(self, PlotsUI):
        PlotsUI.setObjectName("PlotsUI")
        PlotsUI.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.NonModal)
        PlotsUI.resize(1041, 799)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, 
                     QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(PlotsUI.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        PlotsUI.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(PlotsUI)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.plotLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.plotLayout.setObjectName("plotLayout")
        self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.plotLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(PlotsUI)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(PlotsUI)

    def retranslateUi(self, PlotsUI):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        PlotsUI.setWindowTitle(_translate("PlotsUI", "Plots"))

#DataSeriesMgr is given a collection of values for a user selected electronic signal 
#found in the stream of binary data frames. One instance of this class is dedicated to
#manage the values of one electronic signal.
class DataSeriesMgr:
    def __init__(self, frameMultiple, timeRange, dataSeries):
        self._dataSeries = dataSeries 
        #frame multiple will typically be number of binary data frames required
        #for 1 second of data (default 100 frames)
        self._frameMultiple = frameMultiple

        #create a data deque to support the windowing of animated data
        #timeRange is the number of framesMultiples(seconds) of data stored in deque
        self._dataDeque = deque(maxlen=timeRange)
        self._timeRange = timeRange

        #index into dataSeries
        #keep track of what data has been processed
        self._xValueIndex = 0 #byte number in buffer from binary file
        self._dataSeriesSz = len(dataSeries)

        #get the first available xvalue and yvalue arrays to help facilitate
        #the calculation of x axis limits (by default 100 frames of data at a time)
        self._nextXValues, self._nextYValues = self.XYDataSetsForAnimation()
        if self._nextXValues is not None:
            self._nextXLimits = (self._nextXValues[0], self._nextXValues[0] + 
                                 self._timeRange)
        else:
            self._nextXLimits = (None, None)

    @property
    def DataDeque(self):
        return self._dataDeque

    @property
    def TimeRange(self):
        return self._timeRange

    @property
    def NextXValues(self):
        return self._nextXValues

    def GetXYValueArrays(self):
        allXValues = []
        allYValues = []
        #xyDataDeque is a collection of x values, y values tuples each 1 sec in duration
        #convert what's in the deque to arrays of x and y values
        xyDataArray = list(self._dataDeque)
        for dataSet in xyDataArray:
            for xval in dataSet[0]:
                allXValues.append(xval)
            for yval in dataSet[1]:
                allYValues.append(yval)
        #and set the data for the plot line
        #print(f'{key}-NumOfX:  {len(allXValues)}\n\r')
        return allXValues,allYValues

    def GatherFrameData(self, dataSubSet):
        consolidatedXData = []
        consolidatedYData = []
        for frameData in dataSubSet:  # each frame of data subset will have one or more data points
            for dataPointTuple in frameData:  # (unimportantValue, x, y) values
                if dataPointTuple[0] is None: #no data in this frame
                    continue
                consolidatedXData.append(dataPointTuple[1])
                consolidatedYData.append(dataPointTuple[2])
        return consolidatedXData,consolidatedYData

    def XYDataSetsForAnimation(self):
        index = self._xValueIndex #the current location in the data array for animation
        nextIndex = index + self._frameMultiple
        if nextIndex > self._dataSeriesSz: #we are beyond the number of frames
            #there are no more data points to plot for this specific signal
            return None, None
        dataSubset = self._dataSeries[index:nextIndex]
        self._xValueIndex = nextIndex #prepare index for next subset of data to be animated
        #gather data points from data subset
        xyDataSet = self.GatherFrameData(dataSubset)
        #add it to the deque
        # the deque holds a window of a number of seconds of data
        self._dataDeque.append(xyDataSet)
        #convert the deque to arrays of x and y values
        xValues, yValues = self.GetXYValueArrays()
        return xValues, yValues

    def NextXYDataSets(self):
        xValues = self._nextXValues
        yValues = self._nextYValues
        xlimits = self._nextXLimits
        self._nextXValues, self._nextYValues = self.XYDataSetsForAnimation()
        if self._nextXValues is not None:
            self._nextXLimits = (self._nextXValues[0], self._nextXValues[0] + 
                                 self._timeRange)
        else:
            self._nextXLimits = (None, None)
        return xValues, yValues, xlimits

class Graph:
    def __init__(self, title, dataSeriesMgr):
        self._title = title
        self._ax = None
        self._line2d = None
        self._xlimits = None
        self._dataSeriesMgr = dataSeriesMgr

    @property 
    def DataSeriesMgr(self):
        return self._dataSeriesMgr

    @DataSeriesMgr.setter
    def DataSeriesMgr(self, val):
        self._dataSeriesMgr = val

    @property
    def AX(self):
        return self._ax
    
    @AX.setter
    def AX(self, ax):
        self._ax = ax
        line2d, = self._ax.plot([], [], animated=True)
        self._line2d = line2d
        self._ax.set_title(self._title, fontweight='bold', size=10)

    @property
    def Line2D(self):
        return self._line2d

    @Line2D.setter
    def Line2D(self,val):
        self._line2d = val

    @property
    def Title(self):
        return self._title

    @property
    def ShowXAxis(self):
        return self._showXAxis

    @ShowXAxis.setter
    def ShowXAxis(self, val):
        self._showXAxis = val
        self._ax.xaxis.set_visible(val)

    @property
    def XLimits(self):
        return self._xlimits

    @XLimits.setter
    def XLimits(self, tup):
        self._xlimits = tup
        self._ax.set_xlim(tup[0], tup[1])

class Plotter(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parentWindow):
        super(Plotter, self).__init__()
        self._parentWindow = parentWindow

        #Matplotlib Figure
        self._figure = Figure()

        self._frameMultiple = 100 #there are 100 frames of data per second
        self._xaxisRange = 10 #make the graphs have a 10 second xaxis range
        self._animationInterval = 1000 #one second

        #PyQt5 UI
        #add the canvas to the UI
        self.ui = PlotsUI()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self._canvas = FigureCanvas(self._figure)
        self.ui.plotLayout.addWidget(self._canvas)

        self.show()

    def PlaceGraph(self,aGraph,rows,cols,pos):
        ax = self._figure.add_subplot(rows,cols,pos)
        aGraph.AX = ax

    def Plot(self, dataSeriesDict):
        self._dataSeriesDict = {}
        self._graphs = {}
        #for this example, simplify the structure of the data to be plotted
        for binaryFileAlias, dataType, dataCode, dataSpec, dataTupleArray in dataSeriesDict.YieldAliasTypeCodeAndData():
            self._dataSeriesDict[dataCode] = DataSeriesMgr(self._frameMultiple, self._xaxisRange, dataTupleArray)
        self._numberOfGraphs = len(self._dataSeriesDict.keys())

        #prepare for blitting
        pos = 1
        self._lines = []
        lastKey = None
        for k,v in self._dataSeriesDict.items():
            #create a graph for each series of data
            aGraph = Graph(k,v)
            self._graphs[k] = aGraph
            #the last graph will show animated x axis
            lastKey = k
            #and place it in the layout
            self.PlaceGraph(aGraph, self._numberOfGraphs, 1, pos)
            aGraph.ShowXAxis = False
            #collect lines from graphs
            self._lines.append(aGraph.Line2D)
            pos += 1

        #show the x axis of the last graph
        lastGraph = self._graphs[lastKey]
        lastGraph.ShowXAxis = True

        #Animate
        self._animation = animation.FuncAnimation(self._figure, self.DisplayAnimatedData, 
                            None, interval=self._animationInterval, blit=True)

    def DisplayAnimatedData(self,i):
        indx = 0
        haveData = False
        for key, graph in self._graphs.items():
            allXValues, allYValues, xlimits = graph.DataSeriesMgr.NextXYDataSets() 
            if allXValues is None: #no more data
                continue
            # print(f'{key}-NumOfX:{len(allXValues)}')
            # print(f'{key}-XLimits: {xlimits[0]}, {xlimits[1]}')
            self._lines[indx].set_data(allXValues, allYValues)
            #call set_xlim on the graph.
            graph.XLimits = xlimits
            haveData = True
            indx += 1

        if not haveData: #no data ??
            self._animation.event_source.stop()
        return self._lines
```

Comment: See a simpler explanation, concise code, and an answer here -> [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75511545/is-there-a-way-to-animate-a-graph-using-matplotlib-which-incorporates-blitting-a/75548980#75548980)

Answer (score 0):

By updating the xaxis limits prior to updating the lines in the FuncAnimation method DisplayAnimatedData, the advancing of a window of data seems to work as expected. However, when attempting to animate 10 individual graphs in one second increments, the advance of the xaxis and the update of the plots takes nearly twice as long (about 2 seconds) even when implementing blitting where only one x axis is redrawn and the y axis is only drawn once.