# Is there a way to animate a graph using matplotlib which incorporates blitting and has an advancing xaxis showing a window of time

Tags: python, matplotlib

This post replaces a prior ill-formed and hurried post. I have been doing research on blitting with matplotlib. Earlier I posted a lengthy description with complicated code which, of course, invoked no response. I have reworked the question and code to provide a simple and hopefully clear picture of what I am seeking.

I wish to create an animation using matplotlib and blitting which shows a data feed with respect to a moving time frame. That time frame is set to be 10 seconds.  So, initially the xaxis range will be 0 to 10. As the animation advances and reaches, say, 9 seconds, the x axis limits are updated to 1 to 11. Thereafter, the axis limits are updated every second to move the 10 second time frame.

I desire to employ blitting for performance reason given that I intend to animate several graphs at once and have found that completely redrawing all the graphs within a one second interval cannot be done by matplotlib.  But blitting shows promise.

Can blitting be performed in which only the plot line and xaxis is redrawn?  The included code currently plots data but the xaxis does not advance.  With several graphs in a vertical orientation, I intend to only show and update the xaxis on the bottom graph.

```
class PlotsUI(object):
    def setupUi(self, PlotsUI):
        PlotsUI.setObjectName("PlotsUI")
        PlotsUI.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.NonModal)
        PlotsUI.resize(1041, 799)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(PlotsUI.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        PlotsUI.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(PlotsUI)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.plotLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.plotLayout.setObjectName("plotLayout")
        self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.plotLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(PlotsUI)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(PlotsUI)

    def retranslateUi(self, PlotsUI):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        PlotsUI.setWindowTitle(_translate("PlotsUI", "Plots"))

class SimplePlotter(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SimplePlotter, self).__init__()
        #A simple Qt dialog created with Qt Designer
        self.ui = PlotsUI()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self._xlimits = None
        self._line2D = None
        self._animation = None
        self._dataSeriesMgr = None

    def Plot(self,data):
        self._data = data
        self._lines = []
        self._figure = Figure()

        self._canvas = FigureCanvas(self._figure)
        self.ui.plotLayout.addWidget(self._canvas)

        self.show()

        #object that returns 1 second of data per call to the animation function
        self._dataSeriesMgr = DataSeriesMgr()

        #figure was created outside this method
        self._ax = self._figure.add_subplot(1,1,1)
        line2D, = self._ax.plot([], [], animated=True)
        self._lines.append(line2D)
        #set the initial x axis limits to a range of 10 seconds
        self._ax.set_xlim(0,10)
        self._ax.set_ylim(0,30)
        self._xlimits = (0,10)

        self._animation = animation.FuncAnimation(self._figure, self.Animate, None,
                                interval=1000, blit=True, repeat=False)
        
    def Animate(self,index):
        allXValues, allYValues = self._dataSeriesMgr.NextXYDataSet() 
        if allXValues is None:
            return self._lines
        #When the x values exceed 10 (seconds) the x axis limits are advanced 1 second
        if self._xlimits[1] != self._dataSeriesMgr.XLimits[1]:
            self._xlimits = self._dataSeriesMgr.XLimits
            self._ax.set_xlim(self._xlimits[0],self._xlimits[1])

        self._lines[0].set_data(allXValues, allYValues)
        return self._lines
```

The new code I have tried after reading matplotlib documentation on blitting is...

```
class SimplePlotter(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parentWindow):
        super(SimplePlotter, self).__init__()
        self._parentWindow = parentWindow
        self._parentWindow = parentWindow
        #A Qt dialog
        self.ui = Ui_Plots()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self._xlimits = None
        self._xaxis = None
        self._line2D = None
        self._animation = None
        self._dataSeriesMgr = None
        self._background = None

    def Plot(self,data):
        self._data = data
        self._lines = []
        self._noDataCount = 0
        self._figure = Figure()

        self._canvas = FigureCanvas(self._figure)
        self.ui.plotLayout.addWidget(self._canvas)

        #object that returns 1 second of data per call to the animation function
        self._dataSeriesMgr = DataSeriesMgr()

        self._ax = self._figure.add_subplot(1,1,1)
        self._line2D, = self._ax.plot([], [], animated=True)
        
        xaxis = self._ax.get_xaxis()
        xaxis.set_animated(True)
        self._ax.set_ylim(0,30)
        self._ax.set_xlim(0,10)
        self._xlimits = (0,10)

        self.show()

        self._animation = animation.FuncAnimation(self._figure, self.Animate, None,
                                interval=1000, blit=True, repeat=False)
        
    def Animate(self,index):
        xaxis = self._ax.get_xaxis()
        allXValues, allYValues = self._dataSeriesMgr.NextXYDataSet() 
        if allXValues is None:
            return (self._line2D,)
        self._line2D.set_data(allXValues, allYValues)
        #When the x values exceed 10 (seconds) the x axis limits are advanced 1 second
        if self._xlimits[1] != self._dataSeriesMgr.XLimits[1]:
            self._xlimits = self._dataSeriesMgr.XLimits
            print(f'XLimits: {self._xlimits[0]} , {self._xlimits[1]}')
            self._ax.set_xlim(self._xlimits[0],self._xlimits[1])
            self._ax.draw_artist(xaxis)
            self._canvas.flush_events()

        #xaxis = self._ax.get_xaxis()
        return (self._line2D,)
```

I set the animation of the xaxis to true and knowing it will not be shown automatically, I update the limit of the xaxis and redraw it in the automation method. The xaxis never changes.

Comment: Is there a way to update the xaxis using the bbox?

Comment: I have modified the code a bit after reading more about blitting. Particularly at https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/blitting.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-advanced-blitting-py. Given the constraint of characters allowed in the comment section.  I am posting the new code and findings.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to the problem of blitting both the plot line and a xaxis that displays an advancing window of say 10 seconds is NOT to set the AnimationFunc blit to True.  Set it to False.  Also do NOT set the animated property of either the plot line or the axis to True.  By doing what most all examples on the internet are specifying (setting blit and animated to True), matplotlib will ignore the x-axis and it never gets updated.
Here is the code to update the plot line and advancing x axis. It has been simplified from my working code.

```
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib import animation
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from src.DataSourceMgr.DataSeries import DataSeriesMgr
from src.GUI.Plots import Ui_Plots

class SimplePlotter(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parentWindow):
        super(SimplePlotter, self).__init__()
        self._parentWindow = parentWindow
        self._parentWindow = parentWindow
        #A simple Qt dialog
        self.ui = Ui_Plots()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

    def Plot(self, dataDictionary):
        self._figure = Figure()
        #Attach the canvas to the Qt dialog layout
        self._canvas = FigureCanvas(self._figure)
        self.ui.plotLayout.addWidget(self._canvas)

        #I have made the code create a figure containing several subplots since that is where
        #performance takes a hit trying to completely redraw all the graph during animation
        #dataDictionary can be a collection of data from a file or real-time data stream
        #which contains data to be plotted among several graphs
        self._axDict = {} #store the axes of each graph
        self._lineDict = {}
        self._backgroundDict = {} #store the static part of each graph
        self._dataMgrDict = {}
        graphPosition = 1
        numOfGraphs = len(dataDictionary.keys())
        for dictKey, data in dataDictionary.items():
            self._axDict[dictKey] = self._figure.add_subplot(numOfGraphs,1,graphPosition)
            self._lineDict[dictKey] = self._axDict[dictKey].plot([],[])
            #DataSeriesMgr is class that returns 1 second of data per call to the animation function
            #The data I work with contains x,y data points where x is time. So, the DataSeriesMgr
            #knows how to get 1 second worth of data from the source. It alsoo knows how to determine
            #x and y axis limits.
            self._dataMgrDict[dictKey] = DataSeriesMgr(data)

            #initialize axes properties like line color, axis labels, and graph titles HERE

            graphPosition += 1

        #must call canvas draw to cache renderer for saving static backgrounds
        self._canvas.draw()
        self._canvas.flush_events()
        #store the static parts of each graph
        for dictKey, ax in self._axDict.items():
            canvasCopy = self._canvas.copy_from_bbox(ax.bbox)
            self._backgroundDict[dictKey] = canvasCopy)

        #setup the animation
        self._animation = animation.FuncAnimation(self._figure, self.Animate, None,
                                interval=1000, blit=False, repeat=False)
        
    def Animate(self,index):
   
        for dictKey, ax in self._axDict.items()
            #restore the static part
            self._canvas.restore_region(self._backgroundDict[dictKey])
            dataMgr = self._dataMgrDict[dictKey]
            line = self._lineDict[dictKey]
            #get the next 1 second of data - my data has 100 data points per second
            allXValues, allYValues = dataMgr.NextXYDataSet() 
            #set the plot line data
            line.set_data(allXValues, allYValues)
            #detemine if x and y limits need to be updated
            xlowlim, xhighlim = ax.get_xlim()
            if (xlowlim != dataMgr.XLimits[0] or xhighlim != dataMgr.XLimits[1]):
                ax.set_xlim(dataMgr.XLimits)
                ax.draw_artist(ax.get_xaxis())
            ylowlim, yhighlim = ax.get_ylim()
            if (ylowlim != dataMgr.YLimits[0] or yhighlim != dataMgr.YLimits[1]):
                ax.set_ylim(dataMgr.YLimits)
                ax.draw_artist(ax.get_yaxis())
    
            ax.draw_artist(self._lineDict[dictKey])

        self._canvas.flush_events()
```